# How to add foreignObject to a d3 circle?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to display "complexe" `div` inside a `d3 circle`. As I understand, I can't add a `div` inside an `svg` element unless I use the `foreignObject` element.

I was able to add a `div` inside a pure `d3 svg` element, but I have no luck with a `d3 circle` element.

[Here a JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/emiliepicardcantin/rmaydzx5/) that shows a circle element and what I tried to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you accept adding foreign object with a d3 syntax, this code should fit your need :

```
var ns = 'http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/';

var cont = d3.select("#container")
.append("svg")
.attr("xmlns",ns)
.attr("width", "400px")
.attr("height", "400px")
.attr("transform", "translate(100,100)")
;

var circle = cont.append("circle")
.attr("xmlns",ns)
.attr("id", "svg-div")
.attr("r","200")
.attr("fill", "red")
.attr("transform", "translate(200,200)")
;

var mainDiv = document.createElement('div');
mainDiv.innerHTML = 'Hello World';
mainDiv.style.background = "#000";
mainDiv.style.color = "#fff";
mainDiv.style.width = '50px';
mainDiv.style.height = '50px';

var numUsers = document.createElement("div");
numUsers.innerHTML = 5;
numUsers.style.display = 'inline';

var userIcon = document.createElement("img");
userIcon.src = "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/freeline/32/account_friend_human_man_member_person_profile_user_users-512.png";
userIcon.style.width = '12px';
userIcon.style.height = '12px';
userIcon.style.display = 'inline';

d3.select("svg").append("foreignObject")
            .attr("width", 100)
            .attr("height", 100)
            .attr("transform", "translate(200,200)")
            .append("xhtml:div")
            .html("5 ")
            .append('xhtml:img').attr('src','https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/freeline/32/account_friend_human_man_member_person_profile_user_users-512.png')
            .attr("height","12px")
            .attr("width","12px");

var userDiv = document.createElement("div");
userDiv.appendChild(numUsers);
userDiv.appendChild(userIcon);

mainDiv.appendChild(userDiv);

var foreignObject = document.createElementNS( ns, 'foreignObject');
foreignObject.setAttribute('height', 100);
foreignObject.setAttribute('width', 100);
foreignObject.appendChild( mainDiv ); 

var svg = document.querySelector( '#svg-div' );
svg.appendChild(foreignObject);
```

Comment: I just updated my question. Would your answer still be valid ? I tried that way before but couldn't create a valid HTML string to replace `.html("Hello World");` apparently.

Comment: I have edited my answer to follow your edit, tell me if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: Inspired by your answer, I created a new example with a more complexe `div` inside the foreignObject. [Here a new Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emiliepicardcantin/ot8cq31j/).